# tf.keras: val accuracy on mnist dataset drops to random guess

Tags: keras, tensorflow, gpu, mnist

For transfer learning purposes I changed mnist into 224x224 px dataset and applied skeletonizing algorithms.
[image: Number 5 from resized MNIST]

I want to train MNIST dataset on "squeezenet" like CNN, which can be found [on github.](https://github.com/Beomi/tf-keras-on-lambda/blob/master/squeezenet.py)

The issue is that when training from scratch (random weights) after some time accuracy drops to random guess, see:
[image: Accuracy of model]

---

Minimal code for reproducibility:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rotation_range=60, rescale=1.0/255 )

  test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory( os.getcwd() + str(config.NEW_DATA_MNIST) + str(Path("/train")),
     target_size=(224, 224), 
    class_mode="categorical",
     batch_size=32 )

  validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(os.getcwd() + str(config.NEW_DATA_MNIST) + str(Path("/test")),     
    target_size=(224, 224,     
    class_mode="categorical",     
    batch_size=32 )

base_model = SqueezeNet( input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False,weights=None)
 x = base_model.output
 x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x) 
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

  model.compile( optimizer='sgd',  loss='categorical_crossentropy',  metrics=['accuracy'] )  

history = model.fit(self.train_generator,  
     epochs=self.simulation_config.epochs,
     validation_data=self.test_generator)
```

This is a minimal example, so hopefully it is understandable.

To further clarify the problem, I tried multiple optimizers ('sgd', 'adam', 'adadelta'). I use tf.keras and tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0. Anybody has some ideas how to fix this issue?